# Convert LocalDate to LocalDateTime or java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, jodatime

I am using JodaTime 1.6.2.

I have a `LocalDate` that I need to convert to either a (Joda) `LocalDateTime`, or a `java.sqlTimestamp` for ormapping.

The reason for this is I have figured out how to convert between a `LocalDateTime` and a `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt.toString(dtf));
```

So, if I can just convert between `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`, then I can make the continued conversion to `java.sql.Timestamp`. Thanks for any nudges in the right direction!

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Also, the `java.sql.Timestamp` class is now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes, specifically by [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

Answer (score 321, accepted):

### JodaTime

To convert JodaTime's [`org.joda.time.LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) to [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), just do

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(localDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis());
```

To convert JodaTime's [`org.joda.time.LocalDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) to [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), just do

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(localDateTime.toDateTime().getMillis());
```

---

### JavaTime

To convert Java8's [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDateTime-), just do

```
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(localDate.atStartOfDay());
```

To convert Java8's [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) to [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDateTime-), just do

```
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
```

Comment: Watch out when converting `LocalDateTime` to `DateTime` as not all `LocalDateTime`s are valid `DateTime`s. Source: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#illegalinstant and just running into this.

Comment: got compile error on argument as valueOf() accepts a string.

Comment: @Patriotic: That will only happen if you're actually not using Java SE 1.8 or newer. As indicated in the answer and in the provided links to the Javadoc (the blue texts in above answer are actually links, you can click them to drill down into the Javadoc), the `Timestamp#valueOf()` method accepts since Java SE 1.8 also a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff];;;; I do `Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp(longtimestampppp).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime().toString())`

Comment: Just follow the last example in answer instead of doing `toString()` on it for no reason.

Comment: can someone help me out with this? its not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533213/java-jdbctemplate-insert-localdatetime-to-sqlserver-datetime-column-not-working @BalusC

Answer (score 69):

The best way use Java 8 time API:

```
  LocalDateTime ldt = timeStamp.toLocalDateTime();
  Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
```

For use with JPA put in with your model (https://weblogs.java.net/blog/montanajava/archive/2014/06/17/using-java-8-datetime-classes-jpa):

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {
    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime ldt) {
        return Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp ts) {
        return ts.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

So now it is relative timezone independent time.
Additionally it is easy do:

```
  LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate();
  LocalTime lt = ldt.toLocalTime();
```

Formatting:

```
 DateTimeFormatter DATE_TME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
 String str = ldt.format(DATE_TME_FORMATTER);
 ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str, DATE_TME_FORMATTER);
```

UPDATE: postgres 9.4.1208, HSQLDB 2.4.0 etc understand Java 8 Time API without any conversations!

Comment: can someone help me out with this? its not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533213/java-jdbctemplate-insert-localdatetime-to-sqlserver-datetime-column-not-working @BalusC

Comment: Jesus Christ ... seems Java still messing with dates... I only wish to get the current date classic millis format ...

Answer (score 33):

## tl;dr

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is in maintenance-mode, now supplanted by *java.time* classes.

- **Just use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)** class.
- No need for:

  - `LocalDateTime`
  - `java.sql.Timestamp`
  - Strings

Capture current moment in UTC.

```
Instant.now()
```

To store that moment in database:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , Instant.now() )  // Writes an `Instant` to database.
```

To retrieve that moment from datbase:

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class )  // Instantiates a `Instant`
```

To adjust the wall-clock time to that of a particular time zone.

```
instant.atZone( z )  // Instantiates a `ZonedDateTime`
```

## `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class

Other Answers are correct, but they fail to point out that `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class for your purpose.

In both *java.time* and *Joda-Time*, a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, it does *not* represent a moment, and is *not* a point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` represents a rough idea about *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.

Use a `LocalDateTime` for either when the zone/offset is unknown (not a good situation), or when the zone-offset is indeterminate. For example, “Christmas starts at first moment of December 25, 2018” would be represented as a `LocalDateTime`.

Use a `ZonedDateTime` to represent a moment in a particular time zone. For example, Christmas starting in any particular zone such as `Pacific/Auckland` or `America/Montreal` would be represented with a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

For a moment always in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Apply a time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but viewed with a different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

> So, if I can just convert between LocalDate and LocalDateTime,

No, wrong strategy. If you have a date-only value, and you want a date-time value, you must specify a time-of-day. That time-of-day may not be valid on that date for a particular zone – in which case `ZonedDateTime` class automatically adjusts the time-of-day as needed.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 14 , 0 ) ;  // 14:00 = 2 PM.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

If you want the first moment of the day as your time-of-day, let *java.time* determine that moment. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## `java.sql.Timestamp` is the wrong class

The [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes. That class was used to represent a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). That purpose is now served with [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

### JDBC 4.2 with `getObject`/`setObject`

As of [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later, your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) can directly exchange java.time objects with the database by calling:

- [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-)
- [`ResultSet::getObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-)

For example:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

… and …

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

### Convert legacy ⬌ modern

If you must interface with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert back and forth using new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaSqlTimestamp.toInstant() ;  // Going from legacy class to modern class.
```

…and…

```
java.sql.Timestamp myJavaSqlTimestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant ) ;  // Going from modern class to legacy class.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: As a side note: in the latest JDBC Specification [version 4.3](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-eval-spec/jdbc4.3-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1649214958_4adf759a80a29816780b1ff20d1d6677) there are no mentions on `java.time.Instant` in the "Appendix B" , where the "Data Type Conversion Tables" are presented. For example the PostgreSQL JDBC driver [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/java8-date-time.html) explicitly states that `java.time.Instant` is not supported.

Comment: [Continued] Also the latest MySQL JDBC driver documentation doesn't mention `Instant` too on the reflated "Java - MySQL" Type [mappings page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html).

Comment: [Continued] I am implementing a DAO method and initially wanted to use `Instant` as a parameter to the Spring's `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, but no results are returned when using it (latest MySQL database and driver). Unlike `LocalDateTime` which works flawlessly. We anyways have a **global convention** for storing all the date and time values in UTC , so I ended up using `LocalDateTime` for *querying* data (i.e. pass it as a parameter to `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`) - it does the job without a problem.

Comment: All of this just to take the date and time ... Hope this become simple before I die. The apocalypse comes everytime someone ask about date in Java.

Comment: So... what's the purpose of someone wants the UTC time by default and then convert it to its timezone? It will be more intuitive to take Instant of my timezone and convert to UTC ONLY IF I WANT to do it. Less code. I think this class was codded by someone living in Greenwich

Comment: @MagnoC Not really so complicated. (a) If you want the current moment as seen in a particular time zone: `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Sao_Paulo" ) )`. (b) UTC time (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) should be used generally for logging, debugging, data storage, data exchange, and most business logic because it is precise, unambiguous, and not under the control of capricious politicians. `Instant.now()`

Answer (score 7):

function call `asStartOfDay()` on `java.time.LocalDate` object returns a `java.time.LocalDateTime` object

Comment: It's actually `LocalDate.atStartOfDay()`, rather than `asStartOfDay()`

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your timezone, you may lose a few minutes (1650-01-01 00:00:00 becomes 1649-12-31 23:52:58)

Use the following code to avoid that

```
new Timestamp(localDateTime.getYear() - 1900, localDateTime.getMonthOfYear() - 1, localDateTime.getDayOfMonth(), localDateTime.getHourOfDay(), localDateTime.getMinuteOfHour(), localDateTime.getSecondOfMinute(), fractional);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Joda is getting faded, someone might want to convert `LocaltDate` to `LocalDateTime` in Java 8. In Java 8 `LocalDateTime` it will give a way to create a `LocalDateTime` instance using a `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`. Check [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalTime-)

> public static LocalDateTime of(LocalDate date,
>                                  LocalTime time)

Sample would be,

```
    // just to create a sample LocalDate
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("20180306", dtf);

    // convert ld into a LocalDateTime
    // We need to specify the LocalTime component here as well, it can be any accepted value
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(ld, LocalTime.of(0,0)); // 2018-03-06T00:00
```

Just for reference, For getting the epoch seconds below can be used,

```
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    long epoch = ldt.atZone(zoneId).toEpochSecond(); 

    // If you only care about UTC
    long epochUTC = ldt.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: No need to be using `LocalDateTime` at all here. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it serves no useful purpose here. Instead: `LocalDate.parse( “20180306” , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ).toEpochSecond()` Do not assume the day starts at 00:00, not always the case.

Comment: Whay do you mean by do not assume the day starts at 00.00

Comment: Anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) mean that on some dates in some places the day may start at another time, such as 01:00:00. So, rather than assume, let *java.time* determine the first moment by calling [`java.time.LocalDate.atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) to get a `ZonedDateTime`. See examples in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246027/642706). As I commented, the `LocalDateTime` class is useless and counter-productive in all this.

Comment: So with `LocalDateTime` we must use a `ZoneId` ?

Comment: I think you have missed all my points. Reread my Answer on this page. Search Stack Overflow to learn more from many more examples and discussions. But I'll say for the last time here: `LocalDateTime` is *not* appropriate to the problem at hand here. A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment. **A `LocalDateTime` has *nothing* to do with any particular locality** or time zone though the name may imply otherwise at first glance – learn more about the intention and details of this class. The `LocalDateTime` class does serve a purpose, but not the purpose seen in this Question.

Comment: It's just exactly what I was looking for. Just the convertion of LocalDateTime to LocalTime with the time part to 00:00:00. Excellent! And it answers the OP question without the noise of "don't use it", "use timeZone", etc.
If someone wants to use LocalDateTime it's because really wants to and needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Java8 +

```
import java.time.Instant;
Instant.now().getEpochSecond(); //timestamp in seconds format (int)
Instant.now().toEpochMilli(); // timestamp in milliseconds format (long)
```

Comment: Useful, but don’t really seem to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it has nothing to do with the question.