# Spring Boot: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have the following method (full `JdbcInvoiceRepository` class below) executed in a **Spring Boot** project:

```
public int[] bulkSaveInvoices(List<Invoice> invoices){

    String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO invoices VALUES (:id, :exactIssueTime, :finalIssueTime, :issuer, :groupID)";
    SqlParameterSource[] sqlParams = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(invoices.toArray());

    int[] insertCounts = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSQL, sqlParams);

    return insertCounts;
}
```

I have provided the converters in :

```
├── Invoice.java
├── InvoiceRepository.java
└── persistance
    ├── converters
    │   ├── LocalDateAttributeConverter.java
    │   └── LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.java
    └── JdbcInvoiceRepository.java
```

COnverter for **LocalDateTime**:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return (locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    }
}
```

However when I execute it in test I keep getting the error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO invoices
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for
>   an instance of java.time.LocalDateTime. Use setObject() with an
>   explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
>
> at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdateWithNamedParameters(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:40)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:335)
>     at
>   qbs.domain.model.persistance.JdbcInvoiceRepository.bulkSaveInvoices(JdbcInvoiceRepository.java:40)
>     at
>   qbs.domain.model.persistance.JdbcInvoiceRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3c96bc2e.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
>     at
>   qbs.domain.model.persistance.JdbcInvoiceRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20bcffdd.bulkSaveInvoices()
>     at qbs.QbsApplicationTests.fillDB(QbsApplicationTests.java:33)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type
>   to use for an instance of java.time.LocalDateTime. Use setObject()
>   with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.  at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:1051)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:454)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:238)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchUpdateUtils.setStatementParameters(BatchUpdateUtils.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.access$000(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:32)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils$1.setValues(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:960)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
>     ... 47 more

**What can be the issue and how to fix this?**

Listings:
pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--For less boilerplate code-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSR 330 for DI in Java - @Inject-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

JdbcInvoiceRepository

```
@Repository
public class JdbcInvoiceRepository {

    @Inject
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Inject
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    private SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setupSimpleJdbcInsert(){
        simpleJdbcInsert =
                new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate).withTableName("invoices").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
    }

    public int[] bulkSaveInvoices(List<Invoice> invoices){

        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO invoices VALUES (:id, :exactIssueTime, :finalIssueTime, :issuer, :groupID)";
        SqlParameterSource[] sqlParams = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(invoices.toArray());

        int[] insertCounts = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSQL, sqlParams);

        return insertCounts;
    }

    public Long getInvoiceCount() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from invoices",
                Long.class);

    }

}
```

EDIT
Invoice.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices")
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "exact_iss_time")
    private LocalDateTime exactIssueTime;

    @Column(name = "final_iss_time")
    private LocalDateTime finalIssueTime;

    @Column(name = "issuer")
    private String issuer;

    @Column(name = "groupid")
    private Integer groupID;

    protected Invoice() {
    }

}
```

Invoice table definition:

```
    CREATE TABLE invoices (
  id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  exact_iss_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  actual_iss_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  issuer    TEXT NOT NULL,
  groupid   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Please Show the invoices class

Comment: @Jens Added in Edit

Comment: So you are using a `JdbcTemplate` and you expect something from the JPA library to help you there.... Although both persistence technologies (and very low-level they have a link) they don't work together like you expect.

Comment: @M.Delnum What would you suggest then to solve the problem?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/27829321/1582089

Comment: @Cassian This solution not work. Also I have those converters mentioned in first post.

Comment: Please add the database invoices table definition.

Answer (score -2):

1) Don't use JDBC to try and bulk save JPA entities

2) Use Spring Data JPA instead

3) Define a Spring Data Repository as so:

```
public interface InvoiceRepository  extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Long> {}
```

4) call the save (Iterable iterable method on your repository and let JPA handle all the ORM tasks for you.

e.g. `invoiceRepository.save(invoices)`

Comment: I wanted to use `JDBCTemplate` because this code is for data generator of approx 500M records and I believe that this way it might be more efficient to use low evel `JDBCtemplate`