# Java :How to compare LocalDate with date storing in sqlite database?

Tags: java, sqlite, date

I'm trying to compare between [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and date storing in [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) database.I'm using [SqliteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt) for creating my tables ,when i used [SQL developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) every thing is well ,but for some causes i changed my database to [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) , i found troubles without detecting any errors,because sqlite studio save date as milliseconds. [image: milliseconds].

So how to compare 2017/09/25 with 1511906400000 ?

**Code**
           Controller class

```
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        String date=dtf.format(localDate);
        System.out.println(date); //print 2017/09/24
        /*now i will compare this date to saved date in database*/
        Paiments = new EMPDao().FindPaiment(dtf.format(localDate));
```

DAO class

```
public ObservableList<Employer> FindPaiment(String format) {

    Employer employer;

    ObservableList<Employer> employers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    String querySelectEmployer = "SElECT * FROM EMPLOYER WHERE DPayment =" + "'" + format + "'" + " and STAT is null";

    try {

        ResultSet resultSet = Dbaconnection.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY).executeQuery(querySelectEmployer);

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            employer = new Employer(resultSet.getString("NFILE"), resultSet.getString("FNAME"), resultSet.getString("LNAME"), resultSet.getDate("BDATE"), resultSet.getString("PDATE"), resultSet.getString("NPHONE"), resultSet.getString("CCP"), resultSet.getDate("EDATE"), resultSet.getDate("SDATE"), resultSet.getString("POSTE"), resultSet.getString("CATEGORY"), resultSet.getString("NUMEROSS"), resultSet.getString("PAYMENT"), resultSet.getString("ETAT"), resultSet.getDate("DPAYMENT"), null);
            employers.add(employer);
        }
        resultSet.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return employers;

}
```

`localDate` has this format:2017/09/25

`Dpayment` in database has this format :1506290400000

Comment: Suggestion: Use PreparedStatement. I can't think of a good reason to ever concatenate into a SQL query

Comment: By the way, Sqlite doesn't have a "Date type". https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean that you have Date types in Sqlite. [You store as TEXT, REAL, or INT](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype). And none of those support milliseconds.

You have a few options.

1) invert your logic to reformat your DPayment to your Java format

Forget the Java code for a moment, and connect to the database externally. Play around with this query. This also does conversion from milliseconds to seconds

```
SELECT strftime('%Y/%m/%d', DPayment / 1000) FROM EMPLOYER
```

2) Change your database to use the supported date format of YYYY-MM-DD, and update Java code accordingly

3) Make your Java code use (milli)seconds in the query rather than a formated date string

Comment: Yeah ,i'm using sqlite studio and i have type `Date` and `DateTime`.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine Again, as others have noted: No you do *not* have `Date` and `DateTime` columns in a SQLite database. Quoting [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html): *SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times.* [SQLite is meant to be an alternative to storing text in files, not meant to be a competitor to serious databases.](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-05/what-i-learned-about-sqlite-at-a-postgresql-conference) For more serious needs use another solution such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL).

Comment: @BasilBourque ,You are right ,when the GUI of [https://sqlitestudio.pl] display `Date` and `Date time` , i thought it is type of `date` but in reality it is `int`.Thank  you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can have SQLite compute the current date:

```
String querySelectEmployer = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYER WHERE DPayment = date('now') and STAT is null";
```

This gets around issues with concatenating strings, and is easier to read, but comes with some caveats: you cannot pass any date to `FindPaiment`, and it does not compare your client's date with the server's date. If these caveats do not work for you, you can use one of SQLite's date functions (https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: @cricket_007 ,but in sqlite i have not this format of YYYY-MM-DD because it save dates as millisecondes.

Answer (score 0):

When i created my table i used sqlite studio 3.3.1 like this:

[image]
And this the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYER (
    NFILE    VARCHAR2 (20) PRIMARY KEY,
    FNAME    VARCHAR2 (20),
    LNAME    VARCHAR2 (20),
    BDATE    DATE,
    PDATE    VARCHAR2 (20),
    NPHONE   VARCHAR2 (20),
    CCP      VARCHAR2 (20),
    EDATE    DATE,
    POSTE    VARCHAR2 (20),
    CATEGORY VARCHAR2 (20),
    PAYMENT  VARCHAR2 (20),
    DPAYMENT DATE,
    ETAT     VARCHAR2 (20),
    NUMEROSS VARCHAR2 (20),
    SDATE    DATE,
    IMAGE    BLOB,
    STAT     VARCHAR2 (20) 
);
```

Because sqlite 3.3.1 has not a format of "YYYY-MM-DD" for Date type and it stores a data as long for example 2017-09-26 = 1506376800000 on sqlite .So according to [Convert LocalDate to LocalDateTime or java.sql.Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992282/convert-localdate-to-localdatetime-or-java-sql-timestamp)
it should convert localdate to date and get time (long format) from date and make the comparison.

```
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        long currentDate=String.valueOf(java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate).getTime());
        //Pass the paramater as long (12366332) not as date(2017/09/26)
        Paiments = new EMPDao().FindPaiment(currentDate);
```

Comment: Sqlite does have that format. You just need to excessively use `strftime()` to use that format

Comment: I really do not think you're actually using sqlite. You can clearly read the documentation and see DATE and VARCHAR2 are not existing types.

Comment: In other words, sure. The GUI gives you the option, but it's actually a REAL/TEXT/INT value internally in the database